# Switching windows behavior in Ubuntu

Tags: 10.04, shortcuts

Ubuntu supports a shortcut to switch windows `Ctrl+Tab`, but it allows you to move through apps in one direction only. Direction depends on whether initially `Ctrl+Tab` or `Ctrl+Shift+Tab` was pressed.

1. `Ctrl+Tab` will move forwards, but pressing `Shift` while moving forward doesn't change the direction, it still goes forwards unlike `Windows` default behaviour.
2. `Ctrl+Shift+Tab` will move backwards, but if `Shift` is released while moving backwards the menu will disappear.

Is there a way to configure Ubuntu so that you could go backwards and forwards without running the menu twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with that same compiz plugin, however, you can use the shift switcher plugin, and then press <kbd>left</kbd> or <kbd>right</kbd>.